# Is there any limitation on number of custom tabs included in managed package?

Tags: limits, tab

Is there any limitation on number of custom tabs included in managed package?

I know there is one for end users in subscriber orgs of how many custom tabs they can create, but I wonder if there is any limit on the tabs packaged

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit of 100 tabs in a Developer Edition org by default, which you can increase through a ticket to customer support. If publishing a package that is **not** Security Reviwed, these tabs will count towards the customer/subscriber limit depending on their organization type (e.g. Enterprise). So, you might say that the limit is 100 custom tabs, although this can be increased with proper "business reasons." See [Increase Max Custom Tabs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338281&type=1&mode=1) for more info.

Comment: I can't find the limit for Partner Developer Edition, is this also 100? I see that for DE the maximum value is 100. What is the maximum value for PDE? It is not listed in the link you provided

Answer (score 0):

The custom tabs limit is a fixed number based on edition and can’t be increased. For more information, contact Salesforce.

"The custom tabs contained in a managed package ***publicly posted*** on the AppExchange don't count against the limits for your Salesforce Edition".

If your package is not publicly posed or undamaged then it will count towards org limit.  see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_general.htm&type=0) the limits

Comment: You didn't understand my question, my question is how many tabs can be included in the package